# Screen flash when adding class on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone

I added a click event to some pricing tables so they apply animation class for mobile devices. It works but everytime I am on iphone and I click pricing option it flashes the screen before it applies the class, is there a way to get rid of this?

To see flash please view on iphone or mobile device located here: http://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/ijqBo

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense

```
$(".box").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass("circle");

  }).click(function(){
       $(this).parent().removeClass("circle");
});
```

You are basically doing this

```
$(".box").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass("circle");
   $(this).parent().removeClass("circle");
});
```

If you want to toggle a class with multiple clicks, you should use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(".box").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("circle");
});
```

Comment: Issue that I have with toggleClass is that it opens all the pricing boxes instead of just the one that is clicked.

Comment: Than that means .parent() is the wrong choice. Where do you need that class added exactly.

Comment: I just need it on the box that is clicked, changed it to this:
    $(".box").click(function(){
    $(this).box().toggleClass("circle");
    });

which works to open but cannot shut it and it still flashes on iphone screen, anyway to get rid of the flash?